# An error occurred: IamRoleLambdaExecution - Maximum policy size of 10240 bytes exceeded for role

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam, serverless-framework, serverless

using serverless-plugin-split-stacks in serverless.yml and getting this error

> An error occurred: IamRoleLambdaExecution - Maximum policy size of 10240 bytes exceeded for role Vkonnect-dev-ap-south-1-lambdaRole (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 409; Error Code: LimitExceeded; Request ID: 51920d55-4b81-4b6c-99f1-d9f0ba087cc2; Proxy: null).

when i use `serverless-plugin-custom-roles` i get this error

> The CloudFormation template is invalid: Circular dependency between resources:  [GenerateOtpDocLambdaPermissionApiGateway, DoctorUnderscorelistLambdaPermissionApiGateway .......]

serverless.yml

```
service: Vkonnect #Name of your App

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x # Node JS version
  memorySize: 128
  timeout: 10
  stage: dev
  region: ap-south-1 # AWS region
  deploymentBucket:
    name: vkonnectlayers
  # iamRoleStatements:
  #   - Effect: "Allow"
  #     Action:
  #       - "s3:*"
  #     Resource:
  # NOTE you can't refer to the LogicalID of S3Bucket, otherwise
  # there will be a circular reference in CloudFormation
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "cloudformation:*"
        - "codecommit:*"
        - "apigateway:*"
        - "execute-api:Invoke"
        - "execute-api:ManageConnections"
        - "cloudformation:DescribeStacks"
        - "cloudformation:ListStackResources"
        - "cloudwatch:ListMetrics"
        - "cloudwatch:GetMetricData"
        - "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups"
        - "ec2:DescribeSubnets"
        - "ec2:DescribeVpcs"
        - "kms:ListAliases"
        - "iam:GetPolicy"
        - "iam:GetPolicyVersion"
        - "iam:GetRole"
        - "iam:GetRolePolicy"
        - "iam:ListAttachedRolePolicies"
        - "iam:ListRolePolicies"
        - "iam:ListRoles"
        - "lambda:*"
        - "logs:DescribeLogGroups"
        - "states:DescribeStateMachine"
        - "states:ListStateMachines"
        - "tag:GetResources"
        - "xray:GetTraceSummaries"
        - "xray:BatchGetTraces"
      Resource:
        - "*"
        - "arn:aws:apigateway:*::/*"
        - "arn:aws:events:*:*:rule/codecommit*"
        - "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/lambda/*"

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-layers
  - serverless-plugin-split-stacks
  - serverless-plugin-custom-roles
  # - serverless-nested-stack
package:
  individually: true
  exclude:
    - ./**

custom:
  splitStacks:
    perFunction: false
    perType: false
    perGroupFunction: true
    nestedStackCount: 5
  serverless-layers: # All Layers
    - moment:
        name: moment
        excludeDevDependencies: false
        individually: true
        dependenciesPath: ./layers/moment-layer/package.json
        package:
          patterns:
            - /**
            - "!node_modules/**"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first create

> IAM role

in your aws account with full access to the service that u want then do following

serverless.yaml

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  memorySize: 128
  timeout: 5
  stage: prod
  region: us-east-1 # AWS region
  versionFunctions: false
  deploymentBucket:
    name: XXXXXX
  iam:
    role: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX:role/full   //your role arn
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-layers
  - serverless-plugin-split-stacks
package:
  individually: true
  exclude:
    - ./**
```

Comment: this worked for me.... my resources split into 560 to 399 in root and stack formation deployed properly

Answer (score 1):

#### For policy size limit error:

AWS has a limit on policy size. Check this article for reference: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-increase-policy-size/

#### For circular dependency error:

Check this AWS blog: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/handling-circular-dependency-errors-in-aws-cloudformation/

Comment: can you explain how can i do it in serverless.yml didnt understand how can i implement it in my project. thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

AWS is setting limit on few of the resources like IAM, S3 etc. Resources should not exceed whatever the limit is set. You can submit a request to AWS Support to increase the limit.

Before that, you can go to `service quota` in AWS to know the limit for AWS resources. Based on that you can take a call to submit a request to AWS or follow the above document to reduce the size.

Comment: but that can be a for limited time solution we should nest stacks so that the project can be more flexible.

Comment: Yes. Indeed this is a limited time solution. If you delete parent stack, all the nested ones will also get deleted. If you delete child stack, then it will cause problems will creating that stack again. 

Better to keep stacks separate instead of nesting them.